# Unable to run tests for single flavor when using mergeAndroidReports

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I want to run Android tests for single concrete flavor for my multi module Android project and [merge tests](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line) result for each module into one final report.

Without merging everything is fine, tests are run for single flavor only:

```
./gradlew connectedQaDebugAndroidTest
```

But when I'm trying to do the same with

```
./gradlew connectedQaDebugAndroidTest mergeAndroidReports
```

connected tests are run for all flavors.

Is it possible to merge tests and run them for single flavor?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can't even get merge report by applying 'android-reporting' because it's empty.

Comment: @ViktoriiaChebotar hello, sorry for late answer.
Yes, I'm able to get merged report

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @VikaL. How did you get it working? Can you post the answer below?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem?